# Quantizing to same base colors in RMagick

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

In RMagick you can call the quantize function which reduces the colors in the original image. I was wondering if there was any way for force a specific color palette onto the image. I'm processing thousands of images and I want to be able to compare them to each other, which means I will need them to have the the same colors after the quantize call. Is there a way to impose a color palette or something similar in RMagick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [#quantize](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#quantize) method in the ImageList class. It quantizes all the images in the list to the same set of colors. Also, the [ImageList#remap](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#remap) and Image#remap methods remap the image(s) to the set of colors specified by a reference image.